# ldm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find Tocblock, database may be corrupt

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, dual-boot

I received following error when Fedora was booting up :

```
ldm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find Tocblock, database may be corrupt.
```

My computer dual boots Fedora v.30 and Windows 10.
what is the solution for said error ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this just happened to me. I have Fedora 36 with Windows 11 dual boot, and this seems to be related to having dynamic disks (on NTFS). I had older HDDs and just plugged them in to have more space for my Steam library.

Found more information [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ldm-problem-cannot-find-tocblock-599472/), so this is nothing to worry about.